# Selenium, examples of how to select links, some in TD's, some not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, selenium, anchor

What are some good examples of how to select links using Selenium?

Some of my links are in `table`s, others with `LI`'s and others have `ID` tags.

What options do I have for selecting '`A`' Anchor tags?

Also, what options exist to click checkboxes on forms?

Answer (score 0):

Us click command with:

An '`A`' - Anchor Tag with text 'Calendar':

```
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Calendar')])[2]
```

Within a LI, a list element checkbox with an ID:

```
xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'activity_roles_input')]//input[@type="checkbox"][1])
```

After an LI with an ID, a checkbox:

```
xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'a_r_input')]/descendant::input[@type="checkbox"][2])
```

A delete link for test 'Record12345' within a table TD:

```
xpath=(//td[text()='Record12345' ]/../..//a[contains(@class, 'delete')]  )
```

Checking an input box:

```
xpath=(//label[contains(text(),'Roles')]/../div//input)
```

Select a certain table row (with text "6 Day") then, on that row, the 8th td, then the anchor within it:

```
xpath=(//table[@id='prs']/tbody/tr[td[contains(.,'6 Day')]][1]/td[8]/a)@href
```

Select a table row that has "Monday - Friday", then, on that row, select the second 'a' link, then get the href attribute from it:

```
xpath=

(//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[contains(text(),'M-F')]/following-sibling::*[2]/a)@href
```